# How to speed up EpPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

I am currently adding data to the sheet by calling each cell individually, like so:

```
worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = item.STATUS;
```

However, when adding 40000 rows with 35 columns, it takes a couple of minutes to add the data.
Is there any way I could make this operation faster?

Comment: from where you take data? are you create new document or update it?

Comment: I am creating a new document. The data is from a list filled with POCOs.

Comment: Have you compared it with the builtin method `LoadFromCollection`?